# Starting a rdp connection from the command line to use in scripting (on Windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, autohotkey, rdp

I have an icon on my desktop that points to a remote desktop connection

The link is "test.rdp"

I want to start this from autohotkey in a script.

Any idea on how to start this from the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you are using Windows. On Windows the remote desktop program is `mstsc.exe`. You can launch it from command lineby typing `mstsc C:/path/test.rdp`, where `C:/path/test.rdp` should be replaced by the actual path to your `.rdp` file.